# scanner does not work when I push enter

Tags: java

I am using java and I have a code as follow:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        String token = scanner.next();
        if (token.equals("$")) break;
        if (token.equals("(")) do sth;
        else if (token.equals(")")) do sth;
        else {
            do sth
        }
    }
```

as you can see in the above code if you enter sth in the console then you enter $ at  the end then the program will understand the end of input and the scanner can succesfully get each word of the string succesfully but instead I want when the user push enter then the scanner grabs the whole string and start reading it word by word I tried it this way :

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String token = scanner.next();
        if (token.equals("(")) builder.buildOpenBracket();
        else if (token.equals(")")) builder.buildCloseBracket();
        else {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(token);
            builder.buildElement(number);
        }
    }
```

but now the proram runs forever and nothing happends

Comment: does this `if (token.equals("(")) do sth;` compiles??

Comment: why do you expect that code to come out of while loop?

Comment: @RC. yes it compiles

Comment: @SMA Do  you mean in the second code?

Comment: yes. You are not calling break like you do in your first code, so not breaking from loop and hence you see it as infinite loop where you hasNext blocks for next token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway I fixed it this way:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String token = scanner.nextLine();
    Scanner scannerToken = new Scanner(token);
    while (scannerToken.hasNext()) {
        String statement = scannerToken.next();
        if (statement.equals("("))

        else if (statement.equals(")"))

        else {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, 
 to read new line and save it in a String you should use  `.nextLine()`

Comment: What I want is how to make it work when user push enter( i do not want to use $)

Comment: Just try if (token.equals(""))